# Nginx location for PHP files that do not exist

Tags: nginx, php

I have config(minimal):

```
server {
  listen test.local:80;
  server_name test.local;

  server_name_in_redirect off;

  location / {
    root /data/www/test/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?route=$uri&$args;
    index     index.html index.php;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    root /data/www/test/public;

    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;

    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   /data/www/test/public$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Thats work file for urls `/help/` or `/contacts/` etc… (all redirect to index.php with get variables).

But if url, for example, `/help.php` or `contacts.php`, and this files not exists, I have output:

```
File not found.
```

How update my Nginx config? I need URLs, for example:

```
/help.php     =>   /index.php?route=/help.php
/contacts.php?foo=bar...     =>   /index.php?route=/contacts.php&args=…
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple config for 404 error page . Its custom 404 page.

```
error_page 404 /404.php;
location /404.php {
root /var/www/public_html;
allow all;
}
```

Last part

Important line is ==========   **try_files $uri =404;**

```
location ~ .php$ {
                  try_files $uri =404;
                  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
                  fastcgi_index index.php;
                  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
                  include fastcgi_params;
                }
```